# Cannot style my bibtex file despite using emph command inside

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I use `\addbibresource` command in the main tex file to add the bibliography, so I cannot add an external `bst` style file using `\bibliographystyle` (realized it after searching), and I use a custom `cls` file which I suspect is the culprit, but I don't know how..

I want to style the Journal names in my references to italics format (I am using `\emph`), as follows:

```
@article{Aktipis_2004,
   author = {C. Athena Aktipis},
   doi = {10.1016/j.jtbi.2004.06.020},
   issn = {00225193},
   issue = {2},
   pages = {249-60},
   journal = {\emph{Journal of Theoretical Biology}},
   title = {\textit{Know} when to walk away: Contingent movement and the evolution of cooperation},
   volume = {231},
   year = {2004},
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect on the resulting pdf file.

I use `pdflatex` to compile the tex file, followed by `biber` command then `pdflatex` command again.

This is my custom `cls` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ipb}[2017/07/09 base class]

\LoadClass[12pt,twoside]{report}

%% Required packages.
% Line spacing
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{glossaries}
\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}


%https://pt.sharelatex.com/learn/Headers_and_footers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}


\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%%%%%
%%%%%   SETUP MARGINS AND PENALTIES
%%%%%

% We need 1" margins except on the binding edge, where it is 1 1/2"
% Theses may be either single or double sided
\if@twoside
\setlength\oddsidemargin   {0\p@}
\setlength\evensidemargin  {0\p@}
\setlength\marginparwidth {40\p@}
\else
\setlength\oddsidemargin   {0\p@}
\setlength\evensidemargin  {0\p@}
\setlength\marginparwidth  {40\p@}
\fi

\marginparsep 10pt
%\oddsidemargin 0.5in \evensidemargin 0in
%\marginparwidth 40pt


\topmargin 0pt
\headsep 1cm
\textheight 22cm
\textwidth 16cm
\footskip 2cm


% Disallow page breaks at hyphens (this will give some underfull vbox's,
% so an alternative is to use \brokenpenalty=100 and manually search
% for and fix such page breaks)
\brokenpenalty=10000

\setstretch{1.5}
%%%%%
%%%%%   SETUP COMMANDS
%%%%%

%\RequirePackage{xparse}
%% Departamento
%%\NewDocumentCommand{\dept}{m}{#1}
%% Primeiro autor
%\NewDocumentCommand{\authnum}{m}{#1}
%% Segundo autor
%\NewDocumentCommand{\secauthnum}{m}{#1}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\secondauthor}{m}{#1}
%% Curso
%\NewDocumentCommand{\course}{m}{#1}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\courseyear}{m}{#1}
%% Supervisores
%\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisor}{m}{#1}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\cosupervisor}{m}{#1}

% Departamento
\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}

% Autores
\def\@author{Aluno} % default spelling
\def\authnum#1{\gdef\@authnum{#1}}
\def\secondauthor#1{\gdef\@secondauthor{#1}}
\def\secauthnum#1{\gdef\@secauthnum{#1}}

% Curso
\def\@course{Informatics}
\def\course#1{\gdef\@course{#1}}
\def\@courseyear{\the\year} % default spelling
\def\courseyear#1{\gdef\@courseyear{#1}}

% Supervisors
\def\@supervisor{Orientador} % default spelling
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\cosupervisor#1{\gdef\@cosupervisor{#1}}

% % %  conditionals
\newif\ifdd
\newif\iffigurespage
\newif\iftablespage
\ddfalse
\figurespagetrue
\tablespagetrue

\RequirePackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\fi


\def\coverpage{%
    %\thispagestyle{empty}%+++

%\hspace{-4cm}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{etc/nagoya_university.png}        
    \end{center}

%\null\vskip1in%
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{4em}
        {\LARGE\expandafter{\bf \@title}}
        \vspace{4em}
        {\Large\textbf{\\
            \@author \ifdefined\@authnum \quad\@authnum \fi\\
        }}
        %\vfill
        
        \vspace{4em}
        Dissertation submitted to the Graduate School of Informatics in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the PhD degree in \@course.\\

        \vspace{1em}        
        Supervisors:\\
        \@supervisor\\
        \ifdefined\@cosupervisor
        \@cosupervisor\\        
        \fi
        
    \end{center}
    \cleardoublepage
}

\def\titlep{%
    %\thispagestyle{empty}%+++
}

\def\beforepreface{%
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    %\pagestyle{plain}%+++
    \coverpage
    \titlep
%\ifdisclaimer\disclaimerpage\fi
%\signaturepage
%\cleardoublepage
}


\def\prefacesection{\@ifstar\@prefacesection\@@prefacesection}

\def\@prefacesection#1{%
    \chapter*{#1}
}

\def\@@prefacesection#1{%
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}

\def\afterpreface{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \tableofcontents
    \iftablespage
    \listoftables
    \fi
    \iffigurespage
    %\newpage
%\mbox{}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \fi
}

\def\bodystart{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
%        \pagestyle{headings}

%https://pt.sharelatex.com/learn/Headers_and_footers
    %\pagestyle{fancy}%+++
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    %\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
    %\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
    %\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

}

% Redefine \thebibliography to go to a new page and put an entry in the
% table of contents
%orig:
\let\@ldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{\newpage
\@ldthebibliography{#1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}



% Start out normal
%\pagestyle{headings}


\makeatother
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried to boil down your question to a minimal working example?  Currently there's a lot to sort through to see what's causing the problem, and much of it you can try yourself.  (For example, you can try compiling without the custom `.cls` file.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I made a mini-version of my project with one reference and it turned out one of the packages I used (CJKutf8) was nullifying any styling attempts I made inside the bibtex file. After removing it, \textit or \emph are working like a charm. Thanks! Problem solved.